# R - apply or for loop depending on results of previous iterations

Tags: r, for-loop, apply

I am currently working on a problem where I perform multiple functions are executed iteratively. Foor each iteration the input is dependent on the results of the previous run. Currently I employed a 'for loop', however to speed up the runs I am interested in replacing this loop by an apply function.

The apply function does typically not make changes in the global environment parameters into account. However the global variables can be changed directly. Hence, the following code is identical.

```
a <- 1

sapply(seq_len(5), function(x){
  a <<- a + 1
})

a <- 1

for(i in seq_len(5)){
  a <- a + 1
}
```

Could a change from for loops to an apply function which makes direct changes to global variables result in a decrease in calculation time?

Comment: It's a fallacy that `sapply` will be much faster than a loop. You should try optimizing the code that actually takes time, not try to save 1 microsecond per iteration by changing how you are iterating. Look up "code profiling" ([here's a good link to get you started](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Profiling.html)) for guidance on how to identify the slow parts of your code.

Answer (score 2):

No, it will not be faster.

We can compare using the `microbenchmark` package:

```
n = 1e5
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(sapply = {
    a <- 1
    sapply(seq_len(n), function(x) {
        a <<- a + 1
    })
},
forloop = {
    a <- 1
    for (i in seq_len(n)) {
        a <- a + 1
    }
})
# Unit: milliseconds
#     expr       min        lq      mean    median         uq        max neval cld
#   sapply 55.081023 67.740821 86.924793 78.312672 100.079169 424.137078   100   b
#  forloop  3.950579  4.267804  4.666161  4.492243   4.764634   8.714735   100  a
```

On average, the `sapply` version is almost than 20x slower than the `for` loop version on input of length 100k. Global assignment is apparently expensive, when I also tried running the for loop with `<<-`, and then the difference is closer to 3x.

But this difference is basically meaningless. If we look *per iteration*, the sapply code takes 0.078 seconds / 100k iterations = 780 nanoseconds per iteration.  The for loop takes 40 nanoseconds per iteration. Your actual code is hopefully doing something more interesting than a single addition, so it's probably taking microseconds, or more probably milliseconds, maybe even seconds! per iteration.

If you want to speed up code, you need to speed up the part that *actually takes time*, not try to a few hundred nanoseconds (still less than 1 microsecond) per iteration by changing how you are iterating. Look up "code profiling" ([here's a good link to get you started](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Profiling.html)) for guidance on how to identify the slow parts of your code.